Splitting Truth Files
So I'm working with the ISIC 2019 dataset. I was told to split the dataset by picking the images randomly and put them into 3 subfolders: 'train' - 'val' - 'test', and do the same with the Truth excel file as well, which contains the labels of all 3 subfolders.
I've done splitting the image files into 3 subfolders, but i don't know how to do the same with the Truth file, knowing that the target is to split the truth into 3 other Truths, in which each small Truth files contains the exact content as in the subfolder. the Truth filename is 'ISIC_2019_Training_Ground_Truth.csv', if you may ask and need for any of your instructions. If you need any other information about my work, please feel free to ask away.
Thank you.
